# Make Radio Button Show/Hide Input Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a site and I would like to know how to make my radio buttons show / hide input fields.

The site I'm using ONLY allows me to edit the CSS and JavaScript (no jQuery) so I can't change the HTML but there are IDs on the radio buttons and input fields.

Essentially I am working on a product page and want to only show one `dropdown` when someone only chooses to buy one product with the others hidden. Then show two dropdowns if they select the buy two radio button with the 3rd and 4th hidden. Then show three dropdowns if they select the buy three radio button with the 4th hidden. Then if they select four show them all.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/adrian-england/pen/bmKPxO)

```js
function hideSelector() {
  var seltwo = document.getElementById("second");

  seltwo.addClass("hidden");
};

document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", hideSelector);
```

```css
.visible {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Buy One <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="one"> Buy Two <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="two"> Buy Three <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="three"> Buy Four <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="four">

<br>
<select id="first">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="second">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="third">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="fourth">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

Comment: simply use   seltwo.style.display ="none";  instead of seltwo.addClass("hidden");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below. The radio button can be changed, number of select boxes will be adjusted.
Documentation in the JS code.

```js
function hideSelector() {
  // Put all radio buttons with the same name in an array
  const radios = [...document.getElementsByName("yesno")];

  // Check which radio button is selected and save the index
  let selectedRadio = 0,
    i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) selectedRadio = i + 1;
  }

  // Set all select boxes to display: block;
  const selectBoxes = [...document.getElementsByTagName("select")];
  selectBoxes.map( selectBox => selectBox.style.display = "block");
  
  // Hide as many as needed
  const toBeHidden = radios.length - selectedRadio;
  for (i = 0; i < toBeHidden; i++) {
    selectBoxes[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
// Add an event listener for all radio buttons with the same name
const radios = [...document.getElementsByName("yesno")];
radios.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", hideSelector);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

select {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
Buy One <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="one"> Buy Two <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="two"> Buy Three <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="three"> Buy Four <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="four">
<div>
  <select id="first">
    <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </select>
  <select id="second">
    <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </select>
  <select id="third">
    <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </select>
  <select id="fourth">
    <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In the following demo:
 - each radio listens for the change event
 - collects all of the form controls into two NodeLists, 
 - runs through a for loop to add `.visible` to each `<select>` until the checked radio is found, 
 - then it will remove .visible from the remaining `<selects>`

Also all `<select>s` are hidden by CSS

---

### Demo

```js
/*
Collect all radios in a NodeList
Collect all selects in a NodeList
*/
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[type=radio]');
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');

/*
On each radio, register it to the change event
When a radio is selected by user and then loses focus,
the callback function buyN() is called
*/
radios.forEach((rad, idx) => {
  rad.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    buyN(e, radios, selects);
  });
});

/*
Callback function pass Event Object, and 2 NodeLists
The first loop will add .visible to each select.
It is stopped after it finds the checked radio.
The second loop then starts and removes .visible for the
remaining selects.
*/
function buyN(e, radios, selects) {
  var chk;
  for (chk = 0; chk < radios.length; chk++) {
    selects[chk].classList.add('visible');
    if (radios[chk].checked) {
      break;
    }
  }
  var hide = chk + 1;
  for (hide; hide < radios.length; hide++) {
    selects[hide].classList.remove('visible');
  }
}
```

```css
.visible {
  display: block;
}

select {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Buy One <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="one"> Buy Two <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="two"> Buy Three <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="three"> Buy Four <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="four">

<br>
<select id="first">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="second">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="third">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="fourth">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is a jQuery method.

Since you're not using jQuery, use [`classList.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead.

```js
function hideSelector() {
  var seltwo = document.getElementById("second");

  seltwo.classList.add("hidden");
};

document.getElementById("one").addEventListener("click", hideSelector);
```

```css
.visible {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Buy One <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="one"> Buy Two <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="two"> Buy Three <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="three"> Buy Four <input type="radio" name="yesno" id="four">

<br>
<select id="first">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="second">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="third">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="fourth">
  <option value="chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
```